# NodeJS express server's response very slow for first request after a long idle time

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a simple nodejs express server where I am running into an issue where the first request after a long idle time is extremely slow. Eg - 3-4 mins. The same or similar request for the 2nd and 3rd time takes a few milliseconds.

I took a look at this page - https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-performance.html and have done the following things -

1. Use gzip compression
2. Set NODE_ENV to production

But I still run into the issue where the first request is extremely slow.

The server is doing the following -

1. At startup I read from a large text file that contains a list of strings. Each of these strings is added to an array. The size of the array is normally around 3.5 million entries.
2. Users provide a string input and I loop over all the entries in the array and search for matches using [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and return the matches.

I have also tried increasing the memory for the server --max-old-space-size from 4096 to 8192 but this does not help. I am new to using nodejs/express, please let me know if there is anything else I need to consider/look into.

Thanks.

Here is the source -

```js
var compression = require('compression')
const express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const fs = require('fs') 

// Get command line arguments

const datafile = process.argv[2];
const port = Number(process.argv[3]);

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  console.log("Starting in production mode");
}

// Init

const app = express()

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.text());
app.use(compression());

app.post('/', (request, response) => {
  var query = JSON.parse(request.body).query;
  var results = SearchData(query);
  response.send(results);
})

// Init server

app.listen(port, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.log('Something bad happened', err)
  }
  console.log(`server is listening on port ${port}`)
})

console.log('Caching Data');

var data = fs.readFileSync('/datafile.txt', 'utf8');
var datalist = data.toString().split('\n');

var loc = [];
for (var i = 0; i < datalist.length; i++) {
  const element = datalist[i];
  const dataRaw = element.split(',');
  const dataStr = dataRaw[0];
  const dataloc = processData(dataRaw[1]); 
  datalist[i] = dataStr;
  loc.push(dataloc);
}

console.log('Cached ' + datalist.length + ' entries');

function SearchData (query) {
  const resultsLimit = 32;
  var resultsCount = 0;
  var results = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < datalist.length; i++) {
    if (datalist[i].indexOf(query) === -1) {
      contiue;
    }
    results.push(datalist[i] + loc[i]);
    resultsCount++;
    if (resultsCount == resultsLimit) break;
  }
  return results;
}
```

---

More details after using the --trace-gc flag.

Launched the process & waited till all the strings were loaded into memory.

A request with a particular query string at 5:48 PM took around 520 ms.

The same request at 8:11 PM look around 157975 ms. Server was idle in between.

I see a lot of messages such as the following during startup -

`[257989:0x3816030]    33399 ms: Scavenge 1923.7 (1956.9) -> 1921.7 (1970.9) MB, 34.2 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.952, current mu = 0.913) allocation failure`

The last message from the gc logs showed something like this -

`[257989:0x3816030]    60420 ms: Mark-sweep 1927.9 (1944.9) -> 1927.1 (1939.1) MB, 164.0 / 0.0 ms  (+ 645.6 ms in 81 steps since start of marking, biggest step 123.0 ms, walltime since start of marking 995 ms) (average mu = 0.930, current mu = 0.493) finalize incremental marking via task GC in old space requested`

I did not see anything else from gc when the response was really slow.
Please let me know if anyone can infer anything from these logs.

These are the nodejs and express server versions -

1. node --version    -> 12.20.0
2. express --version -> 4.16.4

It seems like the server goes to sleep and takes a lot of time to wake up.

Comment: What environment are you serving it from? Locally? Or is it deployed somewhere like GCP?

Comment: It's a local debian 10 environment.

Comment: If you run with `node --trace-gc my-server.js` does it seem to be doing anything when it shouldn't be?

Comment: sure let me try this. I have not looked into using the trace-gc flag.

Comment: @ZacAnger - I updated the question based on the output when I used the --trace-gc option. At least I don't see anything that stands out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a solution to this problem using a Rust based implementation but the root cause of this behavior was not the nodejs/express server but the machine where I was deploying this code.

First I moved to a Rust based implementation using [actix-web](https://actix.rs/) framework and noticed similar performance issues which I was seeing using nodejs/express.

Then I used the Rust [rayon](https://docs.rs/rayon/1.5.0/rayon/) library to process the large arrays in parallel and this resolved the performance issues which I was seeing.

I think the root cause of the issue was that the server to which I was deploying this code had a smaller processor and I was not running into this issue on my developer machine since it has a better processor -

Server machine - Intel Core Processor **2100MHz** 8 Cores 16 Threads

Dev machine - Intel Xeon Processor **3.50GHz** 6 Cores 12 Threads

Probably using any parallel processing library with a nodejs/express implementation would have also solved this issue.